# Two duplicate ID fields(_id and id) automatically on populating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While getting data from my database, I noticed that there is an extra id field other than the normal _id field. These 2 fields are exactly the same always. However, id and _id only comes when I am populating. Otherwise there is only the _id field. This is the schema -

```
const answerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'An answer must have a summary'],
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: [true, 'An answer must have a user'],
    },
    post: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: [true, 'An answer must belong to a post'],
        ref: 'Post',
    },
    users: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    isCorrect: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
});

answerSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
    this.populate({
        path: 'post',
        select: '-answers -users',
    }).populate('user');
    next();
});

const Answer = mongoose.model('Answer', answerSchema);
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: I had the same "problem", i'm not sure if that's a problem, but i've solved  removing this from model   /*
  {
    toObject: {
      virtuals: true,
    },
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true,
    },
  }
  */ Im, not sure if you are using virtual properties in your other models, but you can try, tell me if that works for you.

Comment: Well, I am using other virtual properties so I'm afraid this will not work

Answer (score 2):

based on [mongoose ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-id) You can disable pass **id** to doc with this code:

```
new Schema({ name: String }, { id: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution also could be :

```
  this.populate({
        path: 'post',
        select: '-answers -users -_id',
    }).populate('user');
```

you cannot exclude the id but mongoose let you exclude _id.

Comment: Ok, I don't mind the extra field, just wanted to know why this happens. Thanks for the help

Comment: Here is the official documentation about it Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default which returns the document's _id field cast to a string, or in the case of ObjectIds, its hexString. If you don't want an id getter added to your schema, you may disable it by passing this option at schem a construction time.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: So yes, you are getting the extra id field 'cos you are using virtual properties, it is its natural behaviour.